# Dynamically update button href with language of page (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am working on a site that has products that have downloadable PDFs for each product. Im using ACF to attach files to the product to download. The site has to be able to translate from English to French and when you switch the language it also has to download the French PDF and not the English. I am using Beaver Builder and have setup the English buttons using wpbb short codes to get the link of the product. I am using TranslatePress to translate the page and the url link includes /en/ or /fr/ respectively to the language. I need a way to hide French download buttons when in English and vice versa when in French. Open to any solutions.

```
<div id="en_buttons">
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="[wpbb post:acf type='file' name='sds_en']" target="_blank"><button class="sds">SDS</button></a>
        <a href="[wpbb post:acf type='file' name='tds_en']" target="_blank"><button class="tds">TDS</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fr_buttons">
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="[wpbb post:acf type='file' name='sds_fr']" target="_blank"><button class="sds">SDS</button></a>
        <a href="[wpbb post:acf type='file' name='tds_fr']" target="_blank"><button class="tds">TDS</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```